# Does the increase (i.e. more positive) of an equilibrium potential always cause the membrane potential to increase (i.e. the cell depolarizes)?

Tags: neuroscience, neuro-transmitters

I am a little bit confused. I know that for potassium, when less ions are going down the concentration gradient, Ek increases and the neuron becomes depolarized. However, I am also aware that if Ena increases, depolarization also occurs. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Have you thought about which way the ions are moving? I'd also check your terminology as although I can tell what you are probably asking about, the way you've worded it is very weird. It makes a lot more sense to consider an equilibrium potential for an ion and use that to determine the net flow of that ion (which also depends on permeability), rather than use the number of ions moving to determine an equilibrium potential. Sure, they're always related, but it's just not very common to go in that direction of thought.